# How do I break this code down to find the errors?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

Full disclosure this is a code snippet from a website to practice for a cyber security challenge. I am trying to learn how to break this code down and understand how its working. I dont really need ther answer just ba push in the right direction. When i run this im getting a registry error. Im very confused about the "snippet:" and "sniplet:" parts of the code as well as that strange looking "do more statement. Any help would be awesome sauce.

```
 ;  Clicking button saves & builds using commands:
 ;    nasm -f elf -g -F stabs evil.asm
 ;    ld -o evil evil.o

section .data
 Snippet: db "@E9>06G@Q:CN3C57I<)<)*"
 SnipLen: equ $-Snippet
section .text
 global _start
 _start:
    nop
    mov ecx,Snippet
    mov edx,SnipLen
    mov eax,6
 DoMore: add byte [ecx],af
    inc ecx
    inc eax
    dec edx
    jnz DoMore
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    sub ecx,SnipLen
    mov edx,SnipLen
    int 80H
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80H
    nop
```

Comment: What operating system is this for?

Comment: It's a simple loop going through the string `Snippet` and performing a trivial operation on each letter. Then the result is printed.

Comment: And could you elaborate, what exactly is a “registry error?” Can you show us the exact error message you get?

Comment: The error is because `af` should be `0xaf` (typo?) Then again that doesn't produce anything sensible as output.

Comment: @Jester If you change it to `al`, the programs writes `FLAG:ASM_IS_EVIL_SAUCE` to `stdout`.

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks. Not sure if that was an intentional part of the problem or just a typo.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen very helpful. The correct answer is changing af to al. I was kind of zoning in on this snippet of code because when i ran it through an online compiler the output showed an error: unrecognized registry af. Im assuming al stands for assembly language pointing to some type of database ?? Because i dont see it anywhere else in the code structure.

Comment: `al` is a 8 bit register, the low 8 bits of `eax`.

Comment: `sniplet:` doesn't appear anywhere in the source code.  There's `SnipLen:`, the length of the snippet string.  (Also, registers and registry are separate words that don't go together.)  In future questions, make sure to quote any error messages exactly (copy/paste) instead of distorting them, to make a [mcve].